# Is there a way to import recipients into a list in Sprout Email?

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

I have a couple of excel sheets with a list each of recipients for my e-mail campaigns. Is there a way to import that into Sprout Email? If not, I would really appreciate a pointer to where I could look to start hacking/building my own importer.

Comment: Does your website have user accounts where these recipients will be website "users" with logins & passwords -or- are they just e-mail campaign recipients?

Comment: @Moto_Nomad They are just e-mail campaign recipients. So I basically have a CSV of all the people who are going to receive the e-mails.

Comment: I think  you *should* be able to import your current recipients list directly into MailChimp -or- Campaign Monitor after setting everything up.   Are you using Craft/Sprout to create the campaign email's from Craft templates?

Comment: @Moto_Nomad We don't have MailChimp or Campaign Monitor for this one. So I need to use _only_ Craft.

Comment: I don't think Sprout Email works as a Bulk emailer on its own.    What mail service are you using?     How many recipients do you have?    MailChimp service exists for a reason..... they are really good at what they do.

Comment: @Moto_Nomad The problem is that I have around 5-6 lists of about 15-20 people now, so it's not a lot of people. But it will expand to probably around 20-30 lists later on, which could become hard to maintain in the "Recipients" list in Sprout Email. And I'd rather not have my client create a MailChimp account in addition, since that's one more thing to deal with.

Comment: Again, I believe Sprout Email is NOT designed to send bulk email to lists ON ITS OWN.   I believe that Sprout syncs craft user lists to MailChimp/CampaignMonitor list and lets those services handle the task of bulk sending and delivering messages to recipients' in-boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Sprout Email 2.x is not designed to be sending bulk email on it's own (September 2016). The feature is on our list to explore in future releases, and currently, Sprout Email can be used to manage sending bulk email via a third party mailer such as MailChimp or Campaign Monitor.

The current incarnation of "Recipient Lists" in Sprout Email is meant to be for very simple use cases where you may need to send Notification emails to a small list of people.  We will be revisiting the Recipient List feature to handle larger lists and integrations in the future.

Comment: Okay. Would it be possible to add an import-button to the Recipients List? So that I could import a csv? Because, as I mentioned in the comments above, my lists aren't that big, it's just that there'll potentially be a lot of them.

Comment: We won't be adding support for importing lists until we refactor the lists functionality. If you'd like to import multiple lists you may need to write a custom script right now.